# Large Margin Classifier

Tags: python, svm

I am building a classifier to maximize the margin between positively and negatively labelled points.
I am using sklearn.LinearSVC to do this. I have to find both the weights (a vector, theta) and intercept ( a scalar theta_0). I also need to calculate the maximum margin. So, I wrote the below code.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn 
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

# training data
X_train = np.array([[0,0],[2,0],[3,0],[0,2],[2,2],[5,1],[5,2],[2,4],[4,4],[5,5]])
y_train = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1]


classifier = LinearSVC(random_state = 0, C=1.0, fit_intercept= True)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

theta = classifier.coef_
theta_0.intercept_
norm = np.linalg.norm(theta)
margin = 2/norm
```

As per my understanding, LinearSVC is the right package for this; though I see some tutorials in which people use SVC and then kernel = 'linear'.
I am not sure whether I should set the fit_intercept parameter to True. I am getting a different value for theta and theta_0 when I default it to False.

Can somebody guide me on the understanding of this parameter and also whether the margin calculation is correct? Lastly, whether LinearSVC is the right model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong:

```
theta_0.intercept_
```

I assume that it should be:

```
theta_0 = classifier.intercept_
```